# Log4j failing to send an email when logging an error

Tags: java, logging, log4j, gmail

I enabled logging in my application, and I want to send logs error by email (gmail account). I:

1. Set up a java project
2. add activation.jar , log4j.java and mail.jar (java mail)
3. I added those libraries to the project class path
4. I added log4j.properties and I configured it like this :

```
log4j.rootLogger= mainlogger, Email, dest
log4j.appender.mainlogger=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.mainlogger.target=System.out
log4j.appender.mainlogger.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.mainlogger.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS} %p %-4r [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n
log4j.appender.dest=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.dest.File=log.log
log4j.appender.dest.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.dest.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS} %p %-4r [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n
```

**Configuring the SMTP appender**

```
log4j.appender.Email=org.apache.log4j.net.SMTPAppender
log4j.appender.Email.BufferSize=512
log4j.appender.Email.Threshold=ERROR
log4j.appender.Email.SMTPHost=smtp.gmail.com
log4j.appender.Email.SMTPUsername=myusername
log4j.appender.Email.SMTPPassword=mypassword
log4j.appender.Email.From=myemail@gmail.com 
log4j.appender.Email.To=myotheremail@gmail.com
log4j.appender.Email.Subject=Error Report
log4j.appender.Email.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.Email.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n
```

There is nothing that happened no email sent and no error shown , and I do not understand why, Please any idea about that topic ???

Comment: @Swaranga, probably because of poor formatting. Check the original.

Answer (score 8):

The SMTP Appender provided by Log4J does not setup the necessary parameters to support GMail by default. It does not issue the STARTTLS command to initiate a SMTP session. You could  rectify this by:

- Either writing your own appender to support sending of messages to the GMail SMTP server.
- Or, by using the [Log4j SMTP Appender for Gmail](http://code.google.com/p/log4j-gmail-smtp-appender/). Disclaimer: I haven't used this project.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a example :
(because I tried very hard for a few days,now its works)

**the trick is : log4j.appender.gmail.SMTPProtocol=smtps**

```
> log4j.rootLogger= ERROR,gmail
> log4j.appender.gmail=org.apache.log4j.net.SMTPAppender
> log4j.appender.gmail.SMTPProtocol=smtps         
> log4j.appender.gmail.SMTPUsername=dummy@gmail.com
> log4j.appender.gmail.SMTPPassword=Your gmail password
> log4j.appender.gmail.threshold=error
> log4j.appender.gmail.SMTPHost=smtp.gmail.com
> log4j.appender.gmail.SMTPPort=465
> log4j.appender.gmail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
> log4j.appender.gmail.Subject=Logging Message via Gmail
> log4j.appender.gmail.To=dummy@example.com
> log4j.appender.gmail.From=dummy@gmail.com
> log4j.appender.gmail.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
> log4j.appender.gmail.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss}[%M] %-5p %C - %m%n 
>log4j.appender.gmail.BufferSize=5
```

Comment: This line may be needed too:

`log4j.appender.gmail.smtp.auth=true`

Comment: @leventunver No, SMTPProtocol=smtps is sufficient with SMTPPort=465.

Comment: I see the exception `java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect
 at javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 587` please help. I have given my UN/Passwd still not working. How do I add SMTPProtocol for logback.

Answer (score 4):

I faced the same problem with connecting to GMail SMTP server and now
I have resolved it. The following piece of Code I used to send email
with Log4j.properties file setting.

I am using the Log4j.1.2.16 version with JDK1.6

Please find below the steps to resolve the problem:

First step initialize the `System.getProperties(key,value)`. To connect to GMail, you have to make the following code changes

```
static
{
     System.setProperty("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
     System.setProperty("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
     System.setProperty("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
     System.setProperty("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
     System.setProperty("mail.smtp.user","xxx@gmail.com");
     System.setProperty("mail.smtp.starttls.enable","true");
     System.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
     System.setProperty("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
     System.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
     System.setProperty("mail.smtp.port", "465");
     System.setProperty("mail.smtp.quitwait", "false");
}
```

Second see the log4j.properties file setting:

```
    log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, FILE, email
    log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
    log4j.appender.FILE.maxFileSize=8192KB
    log4j.appender.FILE.maxBackupIndex=5
    log4j.appender.FILE.File=xxx.log
    log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
    log4j.appender.FILE.layout.conversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%p] %t %c:%L - %m%n
    log4j.appender.email=org.apache.log4j.net.SMTPAppender
    log4j.appender.email.SMTPHost=smtp.gmail.com
    log4j.appender.email.SMTPPort=465
    log4j.appender.email.SMTPUsername=xyz@gmail.com
    log4j.appender.email.SMTPPassword=xyz1234
    log4j.appender.email.From=abcd@gmail.com
    log4j.appender.email.to=blaha@gmail.com
    log4j.appender.email.Subject=Error Alert
    log4j.appender.email.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
    log4j.appender.email.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n
    log4j.appender.email.BufferSize=10
    log4j.appender.email.Threshold=ERROR
```

After doing all the changes at code level as well as at log4j.properties settings, I started getting emails.

Let me know if someone have a better way to doing this.

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely answering your original question, but [Logback](http://logback.qos.ch) seems to support GMail [out of the box](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#gmailSSL):

```
<appender name="EMAIL" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.net.SMTPAppender">
    <smtpHost>smtp.gmail.com</smtpHost>
    <smtpPort>465</smtpPort>
    <ssl>true</ssl>
    <username>YOUR_USERNAME@gmail.com</username>
    <password>YOUR_GMAIL_PASSWORD</password>

    <to>EMAIL-DESTINATION</to>
    <to>ANOTHER_EMAIL_DESTINATION</to> <!-- additional destinations are possible -->
    <from>YOUR_USERNAME@gmail.com</from>
    <subject>TESTING: %logger{20} - %m</subject>
    <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
      <pattern>%date %-5level %logger{35} - %message%n</pattern>
    </layout>       
  </appender>
```

From: [Chapter 4: Appenders](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html) of Logback documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Your code have some problems:

instead of

```
System.getProperty("mail.smtp.user","xxx@gmail.com");
System.getProperty("mail.smtp.starttls.enable","true");
```

It should go

```
 System.setProperty("mail.smtp.user","xxx@gmail.com");
 System.setProperty("mail.smtp.starttls.enable","true");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
I am using the below log4j  configuration . But There is nothing that happened no email sent and no error shown , and I do not understand why, Please any idea about that topic ???

I am using jdk 1.8 and log4j-1.2.17.jar , activation.jar, java-mail-1.4.jar,mail-api-1-3-1.jar,slf4j-api-1.7.1.jar...



    log4j.appender.MAIL=org.apache.log4j.net.SMTPAppender
log4j.appender.MAIL.SMTPProtocol=smtps
log4j.appender.MAIL.SMTPUsername=username@gmail.com
log4j.appender.MAIL.SMTPPassword=password
log4j.appender.MAIL.threshold=error
log4j.appender.MAIL.SMTPHost=smtp.gmail.com
log4j.appender.MAIL.SMTPPort=465
log4j.appender.MAIL.smtp.starttls.enable=true
log4j.appender.MAIL.Subject=Error Alert on server
log4j.appender.MAIL.to=username@gmail.com
log4j.appender.MAIL.From=no-reply@gmail.com
log4j.appender.MAIL.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.MAIL.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d{ISO8601}]%n%n%-5p%n%n%c%n%n%m%n%n`enter code here`
log4j.appender.MAIL.BufferSize=5
log4j.appender.MAIL.LevelRangeFilter.LevelMin=error
log4j.appender.MAIL.LevelRangeFilter.LevelMax=fatal
log4j.appender.MAIL.smtp.auth=true
```