# Hi iam using tomcat 7. i have made log4j configuration with smtp appender to send error mail notifications for internal logging

Tags: email, log4j, tomcat7, smtpappender

Following jar files are kept in lib folder tomcat-juli-adapter.jar,java-mail-1.4.4.jar,log4j-1.2.16.jar,smtp-1.4.4jar.
and tomcat-juli.jar in bin folder.
I am able to see catalina as well as localhost logs but unable to receive emails from smtp server.
I have set smtp.debug true but no use.
Please help me iam beginner and iam trying this past two weeks and fed with this

Below is my code

```
log4j.rootLogger = INFO, CONSOLE,CATALINA,LOCALHOST,mail


# Define all the appenders
log4j.appender.CATALINA = org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.CATALINA.File = ${catalina.base}/logs/catalina.log
log4j.appender.CATALINA.Append = true
log4j.appender.CATALINA.Encoding = UTF-8
# Roll-over the log once per day
log4j.appender.CATALINA.DatePattern = '.'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.CATALINA.layout = org.apache.log4j.EnhancedPatternLayout
log4j.appender.CATALINA.layout.ConversionPattern = %d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss}{GMT+0} [%t] %-5p %c- %m%n

log4j.appender.LOCALHOST = org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.LOCALHOST.File = ${catalina.base}/logs/localhost.log
log4j.appender.LOCALHOST.Append = true
log4j.appender.LOCALHOST.Encoding = UTF-8
log4j.appender.LOCALHOST.DatePattern = '.'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.LOCALHOST.layout = org.apache.log4j.EnhancedPatternLayout
log4j.appender.LOCALHOST.layout.ConversionPattern = %d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss}{GMT+0} [%t] %-5p %c- %m%n

log4j.appender.CONSOLE = org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.Encoding = UTF-8
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout = org.apache.log4j.EnhancedPatternLayout
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout.ConversionPattern = %d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss}{GMT+0} [%t] %-5p %c- %m%n

log4j.appender.mail=org.apache.log4j.net.SMTPAppender
log4j.appender.mail.BufferSize=4096
log4j.appender.mail.SMTPHost=smtp.gmail.com
log4j.appender.mail.SMTPPort=587
log4j.appender.mail.SMTPProtocol=smtp 
log4j.appender.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
log4j.appender.mail.SMTPUsername=xxxxxxxx
log4j.appender.mail.SMTPPassword=xxxxxxx
log4j.appender.mail.Subject=Application Error
log4j.appender.mail.Threshold=ERROR
log4j.appender.mail.From=xxxxxxxxxx
log4j.appender.mail.To=xxxxxxxx
log4j.appender.mail.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.mail.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %p [%c] - <%m>%n
log4j.appender.mail.SMTPDebug=true
log4j.appender.mail.filter.1=org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelRangeFilter
log4j.appender.mail.filter.1.LevelMin=INFO
log4j.appender.mail.filter.1.LevelMax=ERROR
log4j.appender.mail.filter.2=org.apache.log4j.varia.DenyAllFilter
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, Log4J does not support some protocole used in Gmail. See 
[Log4j failing to send an email when logging an error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242838/log4j-failing-to-send-an-email-when-logging-an-error)